# Form posting issue in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, http-post

> Model structure

`UserModel.cs`

```
public class PatientViewModel
{
    public int? inPatientId { get; set; }
    public string stFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

`TaskModel.cs`

```
public class TaskViewModel: PatientViewModel
{
    public int? inTaskId { get; set; }
    public int? inPatientid { get; set; }
    public string stName {get;set;}
}
```

> UserTask.cshtml

```
@model Web.Areas.Tasks.Models.TaskViewModel
```

> UserController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult saveTask(TaskViewModel loTaskViewModel)
{
    return View("~/Areas/Tasks/Views/Tasks/UserTask.cshtml", loTaskViewModel);
}
```

Not able to post this form getting error `500 (Internal Server Error)`, when inheriting another model class to main model class. So when i remove this piece of code `: PatientViewModel` from TaskModel.cs class file, then form is getting posted successfully.

But i want to inherit that model to main model and post the form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solutions. Issue was in Model property declaration **`'inPatientId' & 'inPatientid'`** which is same in both the model class but different case-wise.

> Changed this to

`UserModel.cs`

```
public class PatientViewModel
{
    public int? inPatientId { get; set; }
    public string stFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

`TaskModel.cs`

```
public class TaskViewModel: PatientViewModel
{
    public int? inTaskId { get; set; }
    public int? inPatientid { get; set; }
    public string stName {get;set;}
}
```

> TO

`UserModel.cs`

```
public class PatientViewModel
{
    public int? inPatientId { get; set; }
    public string stFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

`TaskModel.cs`

```
public class TaskViewModel: PatientViewModel
{
    public int? inTaskId { get; set; }
    public int? inTaskPatientId { get; set; }
    public string stName {get;set;}
}
```